# add column to another one row by row

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm writing code on android. I try to write a code which take data from one column and add to another column's string, do this for all database.

Like this:

Before:

```
 A column | B column 
  string 1   string 2
```

After:

```
A column | B column 
 string 1   string 2+string 1
```

I'll try get strings from columns and update column but i can't do.

Database.KEY_COLUMN1 and Database.KEY_COLUMN2 are name of columns(string type)

```
SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = dbHelper.getMydatabase();
String query = new String( "select "+Database.KEY_COLUMN1+",
"+Database.KEY_COLUMN2'+ " from "+ Database.TABLE_NAME );
cursor = mydatabase.rawQuery(query,null);
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
       String column1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_COLUMN1));
       String column2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_COLUMN2));
       column2=column1+colum2;
       mydatabase.execSQL("UPDATE "+Database.DATABASE_TABLE+" SET "
    + Database.KEY_COLUMN2+ " = "
    +Datababese.KEY_COLUMN1+ " + " + Database.KEY_COLUMN2
    +" WHERE "+Database.KEY_COLUMN2 + " = " +cursor.getColumnIndex(Database.KEY_COLUMN2));            
}
cursor.close();
```

I updated exceSQL but it didn't write anyting to databese.

Comment: Btw you can SELECT and UPDATE in same SQL, e.g. `UPDATE table SET column = (SELECT...)`

Comment: `colum2` aside, can you verify that you need to do this updating generically, i.e. not on a specific table? Otherwise, a single UPDATE statement would update all records in one statement?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your UPDATE statement is that an UPDATE without a WHERE clause updates *all* rows of the table, so you end up with the same values in all rows.

If you wanted to update rows one by one, you would have to read the ID of the each row, and use that to filter the UPDATE, like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET BColumn = 'newValue' WHERE ID = 123
```

Anyway, you can simply execute a single command that does the string concatenation individually for each row:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET ArrayColumn = Column1 + Column2
```

or in Java:

```java
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + Database.DATABASE_TABLE +
           " SET " + Database.KEY_ARRAY + " = " +
           Database.KEY_COLUMN1 + " + " + Database.KEY_COLUMN2);
```

Comment: Thanks. So i need id values to update row by row. How can i get id of that row?

Comment: Why would you want to update row by row? Did you read the second half of the answer?

Comment: Of course i read. I edited first message. Did you read that message after edit? I want update row by row because i though if update all database it write same value in all rows. If it can add a column to another one, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a forum but a question&answer site; therefore, do not [change your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions "at Stack Exchange sites, “chameleon questions” are not quite welcome") after it got answered. (And the ID column would be a column like any other.)